# Remove a file that has been opened within R studio with read.xlsx

Tags: r, excel

I am doing a loop on different file and need to read a file extract the information and then delete it.

In R I use the package `openxlsx`

```
datatemp = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "./source/aFile.xlsx")
```

However I can't remove the file from windows, it tells me it is open in R studio, I tried to point read.xlsx to another file, and to `closeAllConnections` but it did not work.

Is there a way to disconnect R from the file without having to close R studio ?

Thanks

Romain

Comment: does the same issue happen if you call `rm(datatemp)` then `closeAllConnections`?

Comment: Yes the same issue happens

Comment: you're actually using the `openxlsx` package, not `xlsx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on Windows 7 and I used `unlink` which let me delete the file

```
datatemp = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "temp.xlsx")
unlink(datatemp)
```

Then I was able to manually delete the file without a problem

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not know about this function. It seems to work now.